# Ruby metaprogramming for benchmarking

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I've got a lot of messy code that involves wrapping benchmark to execute many individual methods in a block, record how much time they took to execute, and then send that information off into a database for later reference. This makes the code very ugly.

```
benchmark_data = Benchmark.realtime do
  begin
    do_something()
   rescue StandardError => e
     log_errors("error occurred")
     raise e
   end
end

write_benchmark_data_to_db(benchmark_data)
```

This code is basically copied around every function that we want to benchmark. Is there a better way of doing it using metaprogramming? I want to keep all the benchmarking code out of the class I am measuring the methods of.

I was thinking

```
class Foo
  def a()
    puts "A"
  end
  ... #repeat for b,c,d,e...
end

f = Foo.new()

add_benchmark(f, [:a,:b,:d]) #records a benchmark event each time f.a,f.b, and f.d are called
```

Does anyone have any ideas? If possible, I'd like to avoid using a subclass of Foo, because then a subclass will be needed for every object that needs benchmarked.

Comment: Won't running the whole call in benchmark give you a breakdown of how much time was spent in each method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idiomatic Ruby solution:

```
def with_stored_benchmark(&block)
  benchmark_data = Benchmark.realtime do
    begin
      block.call
    rescue StandardError => e
      log_errors("error occurred")
      raise e
    end
  end
  write_benchmark_data_to_db(benchmark_data)
end
```

---

Here is a another solution (of sorts):

```
class Module
  def method_bmark_database(*syms)
    syms.each do |sym|
      old=instance_method(sym)
      define_method(sym) do |*args|
        benchmark_data = Benchmark.realtime do
          begin
            old.call(*args)
          rescue StandardError => e
            log_errors("error occurred")
            raise e
          end
        end
        write_benchmark_data_to_db(benchmark_data)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This monkey-patches `Module`, but you could always put it in a module and include it. I'm not sure it works as I am not at a computer with Ruby right now, but it looks right to me.

---

Also, if you want to choose which objects are benchmarked:

```
def log_performance_to_DB(obj, *methods)
  methods.each do |m|
    old=obj.method(m)
    obj.define_singleton_method(m) do |*args|
      benchmark_data = Benchmark.realtime do
        begin
          old.call(*args)
        rescue StandardError => e
          log_errors("error occurred")
          raise e
        end
      end
      write_benchmark_data_to_db(benchmark_data)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `yield` not `yeild`. And it'd probably be nice if the block was explicit.

Comment: this is only marginally better, I think. I'd still have to wrap every method call with 'with_stored_benchmark()', leading to a lot of copy/pasting in the code, and potential situations where someone forgets to wrap it with this function. I'm looking for a way to do this automatically.

Comment: @BillWilliamson: I have edited and added two other solutions to the answer. Are these what you want?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do something like

```
class Object
  alias :old_method_missing :method_missing
  def method_missing( meth, *args, &block )
    if benchmark_method? meth
      begin
        old_method_missing meth, *args, &block
      rescue Exception => e
        log_errors( "..." )
        raise e
      end
    else old_method_missing meth, *args, &block
    end
  end
end
```

I think it's self-explanatory. Maybe I didn't understood what you really mean,...